# Keep object in the view after refreshing when using RedirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute

Tags: java, spring, jakarta-ee, spring-mvc

Thank for Spring 3.1, I can make Post/Redirect/Get happen using RedirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute, But it seem like has small issue

here is the method that persists form object, then redirect to the view to show that form object:

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{formType}/onTheEarch", method = RequestMethod.POST)
public String submitAndRedirect(SomeWebForm someWebForm,
        @PathVariable("formType") String formType,
        final RedirectAttributes redirectAttributes) {

            // do something according to formType
            // .......

            redirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute("webObject", webObject);
            String view = "redirect:/formType/toTheMoon";
    }
```

here is the method to direct user to the view that shows form object

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/{formType}/toTheMoon", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String submitAndRedirect(@PathVariable("formType") String formType) {
            // do something according to formType
            // .......
            String view = "toTheMoon";
    }
```

So far so good, but one deficiency. When I refresh the view `toTheMoon`, everything is gone. So the question here is

```
(1)How does `RedirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute` works? 
(2)How can I keep the object from "FlashAttribute" even after refreshing the page?
```

I know for the second question, we can avoid `RedirectAttributes.addFlashAttribute` and just pass in any parameters in the URL to implement the `RGP pattern`, however, I try to avoid this as the parameter value is sensitive and should not expose to user on the browser. So what to do?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned on [spring documentation chapter 17.6](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/3.2.x/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html#mvc-flash-attributes)

> Flash attributes are saved temporarily before the redirect (typically
>   in the session) to be made available to the request after the redirect
>   and removed immediately.

If you want the result to persist for few more requests, you can store them in session with some identifier, and pass only the identifier as a request parameter to the result page

Other approach I commonly do is to check whether result model exist on the result page, if not just redirect into an error page (ie: user not meant to press refresh / access the result page directly, if they do just present error). Then do a client-side refresh prevention using javascript

Comment: Thank you for the sad truth that flashAttribute cannot afford page refreshing. But I guess that is its name for. I will pass information trough URL with encryption as a work around. I have to make sure no escaping characters generated. Session is good too. Thanks again.